# PHP: Incrementation Error - Need assistance here

Tags: php

Good day i have a form which its values are grabbed from a database,

```
<?php 
$questionId = 1;
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", 'root', '');
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questionid = $questionId");
    $sth->execute();

    while ($row = $sth->fetch()):
?>
  <form action="exam1.php" method="POST">
      <?php echo "<h4>".$row['instructions'] ."</h4><br>"; ?><h4><?php echo $questionId. ". ".$row['name']; ?></h4>
      <input type="radio" name="choices" id="choices" value="<?php echo $row['choice1']; ?>"><?php echo $row['choice1']; ?> ...(other choices)
      <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers">
  </form>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

what i want is how to increment the `$questionId` variable once the form is being submitted. i tried this

```
if (isset($_GET['choices'])) {
    echo $_GET['choices'];
    $questionId = $questionId + 1;

  }
```

the question id updated but just once.
i need it to always update by adding 1 to it.

Comment: Surely, you don't know about sessions.

Comment: @u_mulder guess i need some help from you.

what i want is to update the variable `$questionId` by incrementing it by 1 once the form is submitted. Please suggest a method for me

Comment: As @u_mulder pointed out: use sessions. http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" >

  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $_SESSION['id']=$_SESSION['id']+1;


}

echo "Value is => ",$_SESSION['id'],"<br>";
?>
```